# Facebook PHP SDK FQL not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a Facebook app that shows a count of all events created by friends on Facebook. I use FQL to return the numbers. It was working fine until February 1st and I suppose it stopped working because of the Rolling changes for this month, but I haven't been able to find anything about the FQL protocol in the documentation. Here is what was working before:

```
$timestamp = time(); // Get current Unix time
$iso8601 = date('c', $timestamp); // Convert unix time to ISO8601

// FQL Multiquery
$fql_query = '{"allFriends":"SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()",' 
          .'"allEvents":"SELECT+eid+FROM+event_member+WHERE+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+#allFriends)+AND+start_time>=\''.$iso8601.'\'",'
          .'"creators":"SELECT+creator+FROM+event+WHERE+eid+IN+(SELECT+eid+FROM+#allEvents)"}'
          . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
// Get FQL through Graph API call
    $fql = $facebook->api('/fql?q=' . $fql_query);
```

But now when the script runs I receive this exception:

> FacebookApiException: OAuthException: (#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.

What should I change to fix it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well I never figured out how to fix the multi-query in the question, but I did workout a workaround if anyone is having the same problem. 
I had to make two separate fql calls and used the output to accomplish my task. Here is the code:

```
$timestamp = time(); // Get current Unix time
$iso8601 = date('c', $timestamp); // Convert unix time to ISO8601

// FQL Queries
//Select Events created by user's Friends
$fql_query = 'SELECT+creator+FROM+event+WHERE+eid+IN+' .
'(SELECT+eid+FROM+event_member+WHERE+start_time>=\'' . 
$iso8601.'\'+AND+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()))' . 
&access_token=' . $access_token;

$fql = $facebook->api('/fql?q=' . $fql_query);

// Get friend_count from user table 
$fql_query2 = 'SELECT+friend_count+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()' . 
&access_token=' . $access_token;

$fql2 = $facebook->api('/fql?q=' . $fql_query2);
```

I know it isn't very efficient and definitely ugly, so if anyone has a way to fix my original problem, I'll gladly accept that answer.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$fql = 'SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid = me()';
$result = client->api('/fql', 'GET', ['q' => $fql, 'access_token' => 'access-token-here']);
```